# Solving recurrence equations

Tags: algorithm, iteration, big-o, relation, recurrence

My professor gave me some practice problems to do. But they aren't homework or graded, it's meant to be practice for an upcoming quiz. I would ask my professor, but she's notorious for not being very helpful. But im struggling with this problem, and was hoping to get some help.

The problem is as follows:

T(n) = 1            if n = 1

T(n-1) + n(n-1)     if n>= 2

She gives a hint to use a summation, and to assume n = 2^k

So far this is what I have:

T(n) = T(n-1) + n(n-1)

T(n-1) = T(n-2) + n-1(n-2)

T(n-2) = T(n-3) + n-2(n-3)

Therefore...

T(n) = T(n-3) + n(n-1) + n-1(n-2) + n-2(n-3)

this is about when I get stumped, but i tried to push forward and guess which summation to use.

T(n) = T(n-k) + (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by telescoping the series, `T(n) = 1 + sum(i(i-1) for i = 2..n)`. That's n(n-1)(n+1)/3 + 1 according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(i(i-1)%20for%20i%20%3D%202..n)%20%2B%201).

Or if you want to do it by hand,

```
sum(i(i-1) for i = 2..n)
= sum(i(i-1) for i = 1..n) 
= sum(i^2 for i = 1..n) - sum(i for i = 1..n)
```

And then use the well known equations for sums of consecutive squares, and sums of consecutive integers.

Comment: So this would really just be O(n^3) either way right?

Comment: Yes, n(n-1)(n+1)/3 + 1 is O(n^3).